# Getting version number into the spreadsheet

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet on a spreadsheet located in a SharePoint library. Major and minor versions are enabled. I am trying to get names and values of some columns (metadata/properties) into the spreadsheet and have been largely successful in doing so by using ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties in a VBA module.

However, I am unable to get the version number of the document. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can get the file versions using [File.Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.versions.aspx) property.

The articles below for your reference:

[Retrieve File Version Properties And Version Author Details On SharePoint Using CSOM PowerShell](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-file-version-properties-and-version-author-details-on-sharepoint-using/)

[How to Get the File Versions in SharePoint 2013 Online Using REST API](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-the-file-versions-in-sharepoint-2013-online-using/)

Comment: Thanks @LZ-WX How exactly do I use these in VBA?